# Chrome Webdriver - System Policy has denied access to the requested URL

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting this error message.
I'm running the webdriver.Chrome() with selenium in a Windows environment.

When I run:

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Or any url for that matter, python returns an HTML doc to the terminal saying;

```
Access denied, your system policy has denied access to the requested URL. For assistance contact your network support team
```

I'm not not sure what the issue so I need to figure out the error so I can send it to my IT. This is on a company managed device.

Comment: since that's going to the terminal, it's probably access to localhost that's being prevented.

Comment: I think I figured it out, my python directory is in a network drive. If I run it on a local drive it seems to work. So in order to get this to run out of a network drive it would have to have access to localhost, do you know how I would do that?

Comment: ahh... so when you're running from the network, "localhost" will be that machine's localhost... not yours.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to pcalkins I figured out it was a problem with the network drive. I ran the code in a python environment hosted on a network drive. When I changed it to run on my local machine it worked fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

While starting a [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *Browsing Context* this error message...

```
Access denied, your system policy has denied access to the requested URL. For assistance contact your network support team
```

...can occur due to a lot of reasons.

Some of the known reasons are:

- *ChromeDriver* uses port ***9515*** which may be blocked by some other services.
- Your system have security software installed that is filtering this traffic or using network web filtering.